# Animation of elements around center of the browser window?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

Basically, I have a group of shapes in the form of  elements that I would like to animate to fade in from invisible to opaque while arranging themselves around the center of the screen.

I've read that CSS3 animation/transforms/translates have come a long way and would be enough to do this, but I'm having a bit of trouble making everything happen. Right now, the right and bottom diamonds don't move, the left and top diamonds don't fade in, and everything kind of just folds into each other if I modify the width of the browser.

Is what I'm doing even possible with CSS3? I've heard that it's best to try to move away from jQuery at this point, but to be honest, I'm not even 100% on how I would do it in jQuery.

Here's what I've done so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="all-diamonds">
   <div id="blue-diamond"></div>
   <div id="purple-diamond"></div>
   <div id="yellow-diamond"></div>
   <div id="red-diamond"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Diamonds Animations */
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 100;}
}

@keyframes center-from-left {
  0% {
     left: 0%;   
    }
  100% {
     left: 45%;    
   }
 }

@keyframes center-from-top {
  0% {
     top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
     top: 35%;
  }
}

@keyframes center-from-right {
  0% {
    right: 15%;    
  }
  100% {
   right: 38.6%;    
  }
}

@keyframes center-from-bottom {
  0% {
    bottom: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 24%;
  }
}
```

CSS for the Diamonds:

```
/* Diamonds */
#blue-diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 70px solid blue;
position: absolute;
top: 46.5%;
left: 45%;
animation-name: fade-in;
animation-name: center-from-left;
animation-duration: 5s;
}
#blue-diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px; top: 70px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 70px solid blue;
}


#purple-diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 70px solid purple;
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 49.25%;
margin: auto;
animation-name: fade-in;
animation: center-from-top;
animation-duration: 5s;
}
#purple-diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px; 
top: 70px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 70px solid purple;  
}

#yellow-diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 70px solid yellow;
position: absolute;
top: 46.5%;
right: 38.6%;
animation-name: center-from-right;
animation-name: fade-in;
animation-duration: 5s;
}
#yellow-diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px; top: 70px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 70px solid yellow;
}

 #red-diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 70px solid red;
position: absolute;
bottom: 24%;
left: 49.25%;
animation-name: center-from-bottom;
animation-name: fade-in;
animation-duration: 5s;
}
#red-diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px; top: 70px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top: 70px solid red;

}
```

[JSFiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ax4t6nh0/)

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying two set to animation-name properties for each element which ends up overriding the first one with the last.
What you can do is within each `@keyframe` to deal with multiple properties.
In addition `opacity` range is 0 - 1 and you can use decimal values - e.g. `0.7`.
Try this for example:

```
@keyframes center-from-bottom {
    0% {opacity: 0; bottom: 0%;}
    100% {opacity: 1; bottom: 24%; }
}
```

For your red diamond and then fix the rest. Don't forget to remove from `#red-diamond` style the `animation-name: fade-in;` Hope it helps.